# Chrome Flag Paramaters - Touch to hold creates X drop down Button in kiosk mode / full screen mode . bat

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, kiosk

Working on a custom kiosk, users should have no way of exiting browser without a keyboard. I just noticed that when you touch and hold the screen (or swipe from the top of the screen) a circle x drops down from the top in chrome. how do I disable that? Seems pretty stupid to have that feature in kiosk mode. UPDATE: I can disable it if I plug a mouse in and move it up and down on the top of the screen making the icon show and hide right while its booting, then the touch to hold or swipe from the top doesnt make it appear. But that is very inconvenient. Tried booting without mouse plugged in no luck.

This is what I am running for chrome paramateres in my .bat file:

```
chrome.exe -disable-pinch -disable-touch-exploration-mode -touch-optimized-ui=disabled -disable-touch-adjustment -overscroll-history-navigation=0 -kiosk http://localhost
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by the experimental-fullscreen-exit-ui flag. There is a command line option to turn it on (--enable-experimental-fullscreen-exit-ui), but there is no corresponding option to turn it off. The behavior used to be disabled by default, but that is no longer the case.

To disable the behavior:

- Launch Chrome without the --kiosk option
- Go to chrome://flags via the address bar
- Locate the experimental-fullscreen-exit-ui entry
- Set the drop down to "disabled"
- Exit Chrome and restart with the --kiosk option

Comment: What if i am deploying this out to 1000 kiosks? How do i do this programmatically? For god's sake, i use the `--kiosk` flag. In what world would anyone want this on by default with that flag is specified?